# Failing To Add Child from ViewModel on Button Click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, viewmodel

I am new into the world of WPF C#. I have a method in my constructor which adds the children to the stack panel. I have 2 xaml files. The mainone has a stackpanel and the other one has a label.

**MainWindow View:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="VoltageChannels" >
        <StackPanel Height="Auto" Name="stackPanel" Width="Auto" MinHeight="300"> </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

<Button Content="Refresh All" Command="{Binding AddChildCommand}"  Name="RefreshAllBtn" />


public void OnChildAdd()
    {
        foreach (VoltageBoardChannel mVoltageChannelViewModel in mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList)
        {
            VoltageChannelView mVoltageChannelView = new VoltageChannelView();
            mVoltageChannelView.Margin = new Thickness(2);
            mVoltageChannelView.ChannelInfo = mVoltageChannelViewModel;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(mVoltageChannelView);
        }
    }
```

I want to access this method from my viewmodel class to add the child via a button click. basically I have a list which has set of items. These items should be displayed on button click :) Here is the View and ViewModel Class:

**ViewModel:**

```
public viewModel()
{

}
public List<VoltageBoardChannel> VoltageChannelList
    {
        get 
        { 
            return channelList; 
        }

        set
        { 
            channelList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChannelList");
        }
    }

List<VoltageBoardChannel> channelList = new List<VoltageBoardChannel>(0);

    // VoltageBoardChannel has Channel name and avalable as property.
    List<VoltageBoardChannel> redhookChannels = new List<VoltageBoardChannel>
    {
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_IO_AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_CODEC_AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_DAL_AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_DPD_AUD", IsAvailable = true},             
    };

    private ICommand mRefreshAllCommand;
    public ICommand AddChildCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mRefreshAllCommand == null)
                mRefreshAllCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(mRefreshAllCommandExecuted), new Func<bool>(mRefreshAllCommandCanExecute));

            return mRefreshAllCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            mRefreshAllCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public bool mRefreshAllCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void mRefreshAllCommandExecuted()
    {                               
        VoltageChannelList = bavaria1Channels;          
        // Call OnChildAdd Method here                      
    }
```

**XAML View which has my label:**

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ChannelName}" Height="25" Width="120" Name="VoltageLabel" />
```

**VoltageBoard Channel Class:**

```
public class VoltageBoardChannel
{
    public string ChannelName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

The method which gets called on button click. After clicking I want to call `OnChildAdd()` method in order to add these list of items in `LIST` to my stackpanel. Is it possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xaml:

```
<Button Command={Binding AddChildCommand} />
```

In your viewmodel:

```
public ICommand AddChildCommand { get; private set; }
```

Then in the viewmodel's constructor, set `AddChildCommand` to an object which implements `ICommand`. This command can then call your `OnChildAdd()` method. ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx)'s the spec)

A better way to do this though would to just bind stackpanel's Children to a property in your view model, and then you add your `VoltageChannelView`s to that.

Comment: Sure, you can make your command call as many methods as you want.

Comment: @StonedJesus Try this for binding your StackPanel's children: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f52cbe65-0cc0-4b39-b346-7f70e6830aae/

Comment: I tried doing the first method you mentioned but looks like I am missing something. I have updated the code. Can you check and tell me what's wrong? :)

Comment: I'd suggest you do `AddChildCommand = new DelegateCommand(mRefreshAllCommandExecuted, mRefreshAllCommandCanExecute);` in the constructor, instead of creating it in the getter. If that doesn't work then I'm not sure - maybe it has something to do with adding stuff to the StackPanel like that? (Maybe the StackPanel isn't being notified that its Children property has changed?)

Comment: Tried doing it but it Doesn't seem to work. I don understand how its going to call `OnChildAdd()`. Any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Aren't you calling `OnChildAdd()` in `mRefreshAllCommandExecuted`?

Comment: `OnChildAdd()` is part of my xaml.cs file. How can i call that method from my viewmodel class??

Comment: Move it to your viewmodel, and bind the children of the stackpanel like in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f52cbe65-0cc0-4b39-b346-7f70e6830aae/ maybe? It's usually a good idea to put most of your logic in the viewmodel, and not do much in the xaml.cs file

Comment: Yes you are right :) The example seems to justify how to use in xaml but doesn't give me much abt tell the view model side. Can you elaborate my code according to stackpanel binding using a code?

Comment: whoops... forgot to add the `public ICommand AddChildCommand {get;set;}` somewhere in there!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17941/discussion-between-stonedjesus-and-pyritie)